# How can we deal with large number in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have too large number and when I run the below code it doesn't handle it, so what should I do ?

```
Number = Number ^ 103 Mod 143
```

I got `Infinity`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [BigInteger.ModPow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.modpow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Number = BigInteger.ModPow(Number, 103, 143)
```

Here is how you add reference to **System.Numerics** for a VB.NET project:

[image]

Comment: Wow, when I first saw that method name that I though that you were joking. What's the use case that makes necessary enough to be in the BCL?

Comment: @JonathanAllen: I guess to help people score in ProjectEuler and other serious tasks. :)

Comment: Thanak you so much @Neolisk but when I use that method it gives me "BigInteger is not declared " and highlighted .

Comment: @AhmedKerkuklu: Reference and import System.Numerics.

Comment: Dear @Neolisk I tried to import it but 'Nymerics' does not appear in the list. I appreciate your help :)

Comment: You need to add a reference to the respective assembly to your project before you can import the namespace. Look in the project options.

Comment: @AhmedKerkuklu: Check my edit, hopefully it's more clear now.