# Could not resolve this reference error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have been writing a program and within the program I had to zip some files, so I used a addon called Ionic.Zip.

When I run my program its perfectly fine with no errors, but now when I try to build my program as i have finished writing it I get the following error.

```
Code:
Warning 1   Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Ionic.Zip". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
and the same error for each form where I use the code to zip the files.
```

Any ideas what would cause this?

[image]

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your references window. May be an issue with "Copy local" setting.

Comment: http://i59.tinypic.com/wrjcza.png Sorry i dont know how to embed it

Comment: No, not the "Add reference", but the actual references dialog that shows which references have already been added. Check my recent answer for how it looks in VS - http://stackoverflow.com/a/27326163/897326.

Comment: http://i62.tinypic.com/f0dtvp.png sorry now i got it, here it is.

Comment: `When I run ... no errors, but now when I try to build ... get the following error` <-- How do you run without building it first? If you are running without building, you are running something else, not the program you are looking at.

Comment: Sorry, what i meant to say is when I click on the start debugging button it works, my program runs, there is no error or warning at the bottom when i am compiling, but when i right click on my project on the right hand side and click on build i get the above error.  All i am trying to do is create an exe of my program, I'm sure it should be build or should i be selecting publish?

Comment: Ok, I think I know where the problem is. You are referencing Ionic.zip from the bin\Debug folder. You shouldn't do that. bin\Debug is volatile and its contents may get deleted any time. Instead, place a DLL inside your project's folder and reference from there. This way you will be building using a reference from your project's folder, but the executing application will make a copy for itself, since copy local is set to True.

Comment: Sorry, could you please elaborate on what I should do? The DLL file which I added to the project, by clicking on add reference do you want me to remove? and then do you want me to copy and paste the dll file in my project folder and then add it again?

Comment: Yes. Remove bin/Debug reference, copy Ionic.zip dll into your project folder, and reference from there. Leave copy local = true, otherwise it will build, but won't start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing Ionic.zip from the bin\Debug folder. You shouldn't do that. bin\Debug is volatile and its contents may get deleted any time. Instead, place a DLL inside your project's folder and reference from there. This way you will be building using a reference from your project's folder, but the executing application will make a copy for itself, since copy local is set to True.